# Mongoose require failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After npm install mongoose I have exception in this code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

"ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat '/home/andrew/Desktop/Timetable/node_modules/mong... (length: 121)"

Where is problem?

Comment: Did you check you have the mongoose folder inside node_modules?

Comment: can you show entire path after `ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat`

Comment: We'd have to be there to debug it.  Create a package.json if you don't have one (`npm init` then `npm install --save whatyouneed`), remove node_modules and run `npm install` again. Then come back with output from `npm list` if it doesn't help

Comment: Do you have by any chance `.DS_Store` in node_modules or node_modules/mongoose

Comment: path from exception "/home/andrew/Desktop/Timetable/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/gssapi.js/package.json"  mongoose@4.4.7
│ ├── async@1.5.2
│ ├── bson@0.4.21
│ ├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0
│ ├── kareem@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ mongodb@2.1.7
│ │ ├── es6-promise@3.0.2
│ │ ├─┬ mongodb-core@1.3.1
│ │ │ └─┬ require_optional@1.0.0
│ │ │   ├── resolve-from@2.0.0
│ │ │   └── semver@5.1.0
│ │ └── readable-stream@1.0.31
│ ├── mpath@0.2.1
│ ├── mpromise@0.5.5
│ ├─┬ mquery@1.8.0
│ │ ├── bluebird@2.9.26
│ │ └── sliced@0.0.5
│ ├── ms@0.7.1
│ ├── muri@1.1.0
│ ├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
│ └── sliced@1.0.1

Comment: I installed mongojs and got the same problem

Comment: Please edit your question when adding new data to it. It's hard to read.
From your logs I see you have mongodb-core installed deep in dependencies of mongoose but node tries to load it from top node_modules. If you did install everything fresh, it looks like a weird bug. Which version of node and npm are you using?